# 'include=^\s*\(from\|import\)' error in vim

Tags: terminal

When I type `:set inc` it doesn't work and below status bar shows `include=^\s*\(from\|import\)`. Even when I turn on **GVim** it shows `include=^\s*#\s*include` error.

Here is my `.vimrc` file

```
set nocp
filetype plugin indent on
set hls inc ar ai wrap lbr nu rnu et magic sc acd aw sb spr mouse=a sw=4 sts=4 ts=4 ls=2 bs=indent,eol,start
autocm BufNewFile *.cpp -r ~/Templates/CP_C++.cpp
let mapleader = ","
nnoremap <F9> :w<BAR>:!clear && g++ -Wall -g -std=gnu++14 -static -DLOCAL "%:p" && ./a.out<CR>
imap <F9> <ESC><F9>
nnoremap <leader>b :ls<CR>:buffer<Space>
inoremap <leader>; <ESC>
nnoremap <leader>f :let @+ = expand("%:p")<CR>
noremap <leader>a ggVG
noremap <leader>c "+y
noremap <leader>d "_d
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<ESC>O
inoremap ( ()<left>
inoremap [ []<left>
inoremap " ""<left>
inoremap ' ''<left>
vnoremap fb <ESC>`>a)<ESC>`<i(<ESC>
vnoremap qq <ESC>`>a"<ESC>`<i"<ESC>
```

Comment: This is expected. You're simply asking Vim what the [`'include'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27inc%27) option (short name `'inc'`) is currently set to. Were you trying to enable [`'incsearch'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27incsearch%27) instead? If so, you need `set incsearch` or you can shorten it to `set is`.

Comment: @filbranden Oops, I am Sorry. My bad. I forgot that `:set is`  is short form of `set incsearch`. Thank you very much. Should I remove my question as this is a silly mistake? or you will post that as answer?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer. Thank for confirming my hunch that this is what you were after!

Comment: And welcome to Vi and Vim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. You're simply asking Vim what the [`'include'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27inc%27) option (short name `'inc'`) is currently set to.

When you use `:set` with an option that takes a value but don't include any `=`s, Vim will simply tell you what that option is set to, which is what you're seeing here.

From our discussion in comments, we established you were actually trying to enable [`'incsearch'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27incsearch%27) instead, which you can do with:

```
set incsearch
```

Or you can shorten it to:

```
set is
```